# What is the meaning behind "wag imagined"?

Tags: meaning, vocabulary, phrase-meaning

Today I read these sentences in The Economist

> "Lying, cheating bankers" “IF YOU can only be good at one thing, be
>   good at lying…because if you’re good at lying, you’re good at
>   everything.” Thus a wag imagined one investment banker advising
>   another in a lift. He may not have been far wrong.

Could you please explain this phrase: “Thus a wag imagined one investment banker advising another in a lift.”

Answer (score 4):

It means "This was how a wag [person who likes to joke] imagined one investment banker advising another in a lift [elevator]".

**Edit**

Here is the definition of *wag* (plus examples of usage) from [oxforddictionaries.com](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/wag#wag-2):

> NOUN
>
> *dated*
>   A person who makes facetious jokes.
>
> EXAMPLE SENTENCES
>
> *Janey was sure that it was a joke by the wags in the Forensics labs - well reasonably sure.*
>
> *At one point a wag from the crowd shouted ‘Is there a footballer in the house?’*
>
> *Some wags joked that the ‘9 on Nine’ panel looked like some sort of reality television show.*

Comment: Go on, I know you can do it. Add a dictionary link for *wag* :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Oh, very well then!  :)